# How to check which menu is opened and display text based on that?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

Right now I have this code:

```
<header id="header">
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="title">@ViewData["Title"]</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And I have this code in each home/about/contact page. Now I want to make a partial view and have this as _NavBar in there. However, I have trouble checking which menu is selected and how to make the one that is set appear as `active` dynamically.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2 for my project framework.

Comment: Yes, used Metoule's way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by passing the current menu in your `ViewData`. In your page controller, you put something like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["menu-item"] = "index";
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["menu-item"] = "about";
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["menu-item"] = "contact";
        return View();
    }
}
```

and in your partial view:

```
<header id="header">
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="title">@ViewData["Title"]</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="@((string)ViewData["menu-item"] == "index" ? "active" : "")">Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About" class="@((string)ViewData["menu-item"] == "about" ? "active" : "")">About</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact" class="@((string)ViewData["menu-item"] == "contact" ? "active" : "")">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```